# How to force a screen resolution which isn't listed in Windows 10?

Tags: windows, windows-10, multiple-monitors, resolution

I am using two 27" screens with a native resolution of 2560x1440.

All of a sudden, something happened that made one of the screens' max resolution be 2048x1080.

[image]

The higher resolution can't be selected.

[image]

I couldn't find a way to make the resolution recognized.

---

All drivers are up to date, as well as Windows.

---

I want both screens to operate at their correct resolution.

I also don't mind forcing the correct resolution "by hand" if possible.

Is there a quick fix?

---

More info:
If I don't extend displays, but duplicate displays, both screen can show max resolution.

I played with the cable on the "good" screen (display port, coming out of the "bad" screen), and now both screens are on low resolution.

Plugging in a different computer which also used to work now also has problems, this time on the "good" screen from beforehand, with also a very low frame rate on that screen.

Comment: @Mokubai Did, doesn't do it. Also any form of restart of any side

Comment: Was there a recent graphics driver update? Have you tried reinstalling the graphics driver from the OEM _(if a pre-built machine from an OEM, that OEM, else the GPU's OEM)_?

Comment: @JW0914 There was an update, after which everything was still fine. I am not aware of the event that caused it to stop working

Comment: I would try a new cable.

Comment: @cybernard will try soon, but I doubt it, as the screens are fed through one another: computer-->usbc-->monitor1 (the bad one) --> DP --> monitor 2 (with ok resolution)

Comment: @cybernard Different cable, same behavior.

Answer (score -1):

1. Open Device Manager.
2. In Device Manager, locate the display adapter .
3. right-click on the device's name or icon and choose Properties.
4. From the Driver tab, select Roll Back Driver.

Comment: it is grayed out

Comment: *it is grayed out* Lucky you, this is rubbish advice.